# Python: Printing in if statements not running

Tags: python, list, if-statement, printing, in-operator

I am making a python program that is an adventure game thing through a haunted house. One of the big things in it is a list called `owned_items`. This gets items which are represented by strings like, "box of matches" or "torch" appended to it when they find them in the house or are given to them at the start by `random.choice`. Sometimes, when they are presented with a situation, what choices they are given is dependent on whether they have a specific item or not.

**My Code:**

```
#bullets is the variable for pistol ammo. During my testing of this function, it is at 5 when it should start
bullets=5

owned_items=[]
ronald_items=["a glass bottle", "a pistol", "a torch", "a small glass of      oil", "a box of matches", "a can of spray paint", "a small knife", "a pair of      surgical gloves", "a blessed amulet"]
owned_items.append(random.choice(ronald_items))
ronald_items.remove(owned_items[0]
owned_items.append(random.choice(ronald_items))
ronald_items.remove(owned_items[1])


#This part is in the actual definition where the problem appears when it should run
def skeleton_choice():
    if "a glass bottle" in owned_items:
        print('type "glass bottle" to attack the skeletons with that bottle')
    if "a pistol" in owned_items and bullets>1:
        print('type "shoot" to try firing your pistol at the skeletons')
    if "a small knife" in owned_items:
        print('type "small knife" to use your small knife against the skeletons')
    if "a kitchen knife" in owned_items:
        print('Type "kitchen knife" to use your kitchen knife against the skeletons')
    if "a blessed amulet" in owned_items:
        print('Type "amulet" to use the blessed amulet to make this a fairer fight')
    print('Type "hands" to just fight the skeletons with your body')
    print('Type "run" to try and get away from the skeletons')
```

Even when I know that I have 3 of the items in these if statements, none of the prints show up. I'm using ifs rather than elifs and an else because I want it to show the print for everything they have, not just one. For example, if they have a glass bottle and a kitchen knife, I want it to give them the print statements for the bottle and the knife.

Comment: If this is your complete code and ignoring the indentation error under `def skeleton_choice()`, you are not calling the function so it doesn't run.

Comment: look like your function has an incorrect intent and there is no input for it like `def skeleton_choice(input)`

Comment: I don't know whether it is something to do with the question or my failed copy and paste, but the ifs are in line with the sk of skeleton, not at def. There is nothing wrong with indentation I'm seeing.

Comment: @rosteratbest can you show us example of `owned_items` and `bullets` and what you expect as output?

Comment: The output should just be the program telling them what to type depending on what items they can use. If they use the pistol in a situation, it would end with something along the lines of bullets=bullets-2 to decrease the variable by 2. and then an if statement that checks if bullets is higher than 0. If it isn't, it prints "You are out of bullets" and then removes "a pistol" from owned_items. Hopefully you can get the owned_items bits from what I added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called the function anywhere so that is why it doesn't work.
Just add:

```
skeleton_choice()
```

line at the end. Also in the line

```
ronald_items.remove(owned_items[0]
```

you are missing a parentheses.

Comment: the missing parenthesis is only in the question, not the actual program (I wasn't trusting copy+paste after the indent issue) and it turns out I am the stupidest human ever. I was modifying how it did the skeleton thing. When I decided on defining a function for it, I forgot to actually make the function run. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. That, after I added the call to skeleton_choice(). Might it be you just not calling it?